# Drupal + Simpletest + Class Autoloading = FALSE?

Tags: 7, testing

Just a quick question which I couldn't Google : is class autoloading not "enabled" when running tests using SimpleTest?

I'm using the Drupal SimpleTest module, and I'm trying to instantiate a class which I have defined in files[] (in the .info) file. However, I just keep getting a message saying that the class could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that all "autoloadable" files for the module I was testing would indeed be automatically loaded, but this seemed to be wrong.

I needed to add the following function to my testclass:

```
public function setUp() {
  parent::setUp('mta');
}
```

Please note that 'mta' is the module I'm testing, and which the "autoloadable" classes are defined for. I assume that if you need access to "autoloadable" classes defined for any other module, that you need to set up those modules too.

Comment: This is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be noted that unit tests and web tests behave differently.
Unit tests tend to not have class loading set up.

Comment: So how do I get autoloading in unit tests?